# C# Azure AD and Anuglar Azure AD - one needs admin account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, .net-core-authorization

I'm trying to create a PoC application set, WebApi with a Angular (other or variant frontend), using Azure AD to authenticate my Federation users.

I've got the backend working fine, with authentication/MFA working as expected, and showing sign-in prompts.

[image]

[image]

I can get the login screen to pop-up (and with the correct tenant), however when I try sign-in, I get a admin-access required - am I requesting too much scope?

[image]

This is my `app.module.ts` code from the sample, where

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './partials/login/login.component';
import { MsalModule, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: "my-client-id",
      authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/my-tenant-id",
      redirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
      validateAuthority : false,
      cacheLocation : "sessionStorage",
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false, // dynamically set to true when IE11
      postLogoutRedirectUri: "http://localhost:4200/",
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl : true,
      popUp: false,
    }),
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [{
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MsalInterceptor,
    multi: true
  }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Can you clarify how are you hosting what you refer to as the frontend and the backend:

1- Is the Single Page Application (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.) being served from the same Web Application as the API (Controllers)?
2- Are you using one App Registration for both, or different App Registrations?

Comment: For this purpose, it's all under one server, and one app registration

Comment: May be you need to use to the service account service principal for login. With user service principal you may login, but some of the features might require admin access. So try to use the service account service principal

Comment: Is that something I set in azure AD?

Answer (score 2):

Please check if your Azure AD app has any permissions which require admin consent on Azure portal:

[image]

If yes, please click on the "Grant admin consent for **" at the bottom.

If no, go to **Admin Centers > Azure AD > Users > User Settings > Enterprise applications - User settings** then make sure "Users can consent to apps accessing company data on their behalf" is enabled.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It shouldn;t, because this scenario works perfectly from ASP.NET side (With the client client and tenant)